# "No compatible code running" while debugging Unity with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

I run Unity.
in visual : [debug] [any cpu] Attach to Unity.
hit pause in visual -> error.
error is :
"No compatible code running.
The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)."

I would like to use this pause feature to find my infinite loop.
However breakpoints works.
[Edit]
VS 15.9.2
Unity 2018.2.8f1

Comment: Use break points to pause automatically.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem

Comment: Just because you have an infinite loop does not mean that pausing will result in being inside code you control. That infinite loop might be inside, or just heavily involve, native code (eg spawning thousands of game objects).

Comment: I do not have a good understanding of how the debugger works, sorry i really don't understand why pause doesnt works.
The loop is from my bad c# code so why pause does not work ?
I cant pause even without infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. I cant pause even not in infinite loop.